# After deploying My Asp.net core mvc project on Somee.com , i get error 404 page not found

Tags: web-hosting

"I have created an ASP.NET Core MVC project implementing role-based authentication and authorization using Identity. You can find the full source code on my GitHub repository: [link to your repository].

Tech stack used:

ASP.NET Core MVC 8
Visual Studio 2022
SQL Server 2019
Please, could someone help me solve the following problem? According to my understanding, there might be a mistake in routing."